# Bitwise absolute value of float/double in C (decimals lost during cast)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm tying to compare different ways to get the absolute value of a float/double to find out which one's the fastest because I'll then have to apply this to huge arrays. By using a cast and a bit mask the decimals get lost during the process. (I must use only C)

Here's my code :

```
uint64_t mask = 0x7fffffffffffffff;
double d1 = -012301923.15126;
double d2 = (double)(((uint64_t)d1) & mask);
```

And the output is :

```
d1 = -012301923.15126;
d2 = 012301923.00000;
```

So the decimals are lost during the conversion, is there a fast way to get them back ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : I know about fabs(), i'd just like to try and compare different "handmade" solutions.

Comment: A cast does not what you seem to think it does. And what's the problem with `fabs`?

Comment: "I'm tying to compare different ways to get the absolute value of a float/double to find out which one's the fastest because I'll then have to apply this to huge arrays" - There is nothing about `fabs`. Did you read the text after posting? Your question does not make any sense! How would other code be any faster than `fabs` which is either a single CPU instruction or the best code possible for any reasonable compiler. If not, you better evaluate other compilers than waste time with such pointless "research". This is a not existing problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because your cast *converts* the floating point number to an integer number, which means the decimals are truncated.

What you have is roughly equivalent to

```
uint64_t temp = (uint64_t) d1;
temp &= mask;
d2 = temp;
```

You could solve it with [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) using a `union` in between:

```
union
{
    uint64_t i;
    double   d;
} u;

u.d = d1;
u.i &= mask;
d2 = u.d;
```

---

As [noted by Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822812/bitwise-absolute-value-of-float-double-in-c-decimals-lost-during-cast/44822907#comment76625668_44822907) this will in practice work with the big C++ compilers as well. But the C specification *explicitly* says this is allowed, while the C++ specification says it's undefined (IIRC).

Comment: @user694733 I fell into the trap of doing what "everyone else" is doing. Updated to use unions instead.

Comment: Cue the "type punning through a union ain't so pukka in C++ as it is in C" crowd. This method works on *every* compiler I've come across.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
const double d1 = -012301923.15126;
const double d2 = fabs(d1);
```

This uses the C standard function `fabs()` to compute the absolute value, which means the compiler can do whatever tricks it knows for this well-defined function. Also, it's *fantastically clear* to the reader what's going on, which cannot always be said for bit-level trickery-pokery.

If you're worried about performance you probably should look into vectorizing this. Anyway, a quick test shows this code being generated for the second line:

```
movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
andpd   xmm0, xmm1
movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-16], xmm0
```

You'll note that the compiler *automatically* optimizes away the function call, and turns it into ... wait for it ... a bitwise `AND` operation!

Comment: Sorry this is old. Thanks a lot for the explanation about fabs inner workings. How did you get / read the assembly code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert it directly, but to use pointers or type punning.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

constexpr uint64_t mask = 0x7fffffffffffffff;
constexpr double   d1   = -3.1415926;

void print(double (&func)(double), double x) {
    // std::cout << "-----------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << func(x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-----------------------" << std::endl;
}

double c_dynamic_cast(double x) {
    return (double) (((uint64_t) x) & mask);
}

double cpp_static_cast(double x) {
    return static_cast<double>(static_cast<uint64_t>(x) & mask);
}

double ptr_cast_fabs(double x) {
    return *(double *) (*(uint64_t *) (&x) &= mask, &x);
}

double reinterprete_cast_fabs(double x) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<double *>(*reinterpret_cast<uint64_t *>(&x) &= mask, &x);
}

double type_pun_fabs(double x) {
    union {
        uint64_t i;
        double   d;
    } u;
    u.d = x;
    u.i &= mask;
    return u.d;
}

auto main() -> int {
    std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << *(uint64_t *) (&d1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Failed Situation: data loss and complement format dislay" << '\n';
    std::cout << "c_dynamic_cast:" << '\n';
    print(c_dynamic_cast, d1);
    std::cout << "cpp_static_cast:" << '\n';
    print(cpp_static_cast, d1);
    std::cout << "Succedded Situation:" << '\n';
    std::cout << "reinterprete_cast:" << '\n';
    print(reinterprete_cast_fabs, d1);
    std::cout << "ptr_cast_fabs:" << '\n';
    print(ptr_cast_fabs, d1);
    std::cout << "type_pun_fabs:" << '\n';
    print(type_pun_fabs, d1);
    std::cout << "fabs:" << '\n';
    print(fabs, d1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is a C question not a C++ question